# Get WriteableBitmap from url in UWP?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, bitmapimage, writeablebitmap, storagefile

So my app gets a BitmapImage from a url, which works, and I then need to assign that image to a writeablebitmap. For the moment I have this:

```
        Debug.WriteLine("Poster opened for loading. Url=" + e);
        BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(new Uri(e));
        Backdrop.Source = img;
        img.ImageOpened += async (s, e1) =>
        {
            WriteableBitmap wbm = new WriteableBitmap(((BitmapImage)s).PixelWidth, ((BitmapImage)s).PixelHeight);
            var storageFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri(e));
            using (var stream = await storageFile.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                await wbm.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            }
        };
```

Which is really awful code, but it all works until `StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync()`, where I'm told the Value falls within an unexpected range. I'm guessing this is because it only acceps the "ms-appx:///" format, and not "http://". Is there any way to get this working? And eventually in a cleaner way?
I thought this would be easy, but it's a nightmare. I've been trying to do this since yesterday.

P.S. I know this might appear like a duplicate, but I have found absolutely nothing on StackOverflow that actually works.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var buffer = await httpClient.GetBufferAsync(pictureUri);
var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(width, height);

using (var stream = buffer.AsStream())
{
    await writeableBitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
}
```

Comment: This idea worked, but I had to change it to get the stream like this for it to work with uwp (httpClient doesn't have .GetBufferAsync):
                var buffer = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(e);
                MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream(buffer);

Comment: There are two different HttpClients in UWP, one in Windows.Web.Http namespace and another one in System.Net.Http. As far as I remember, Microsoft recommends to use the one in Windows.Web.Http, and it does have GetBufferAsync method. But you can use either one for my example.